# Using two INSERT statements for two different tables in a single SQL statement

Tags: java, sql, database, postgresql, sql-insert

I have two tables one is users and other is students. I wish to execute a single SQL statement that inserts into both these tables different values. The id is PK for users and I have referenced the same id in the student table with (`id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES users(id)`)

I tried this:

```
INSERT INTO users (id, password, firstName, lastName, emailAddress, enrollDate, lastAccess, enabled, type) VALUES (100222222, 'password', 'Robert', 'McReady', 'bob.mcready@dcmail.ca', '2016-03-07', '2015-09-03', true, 's') 
AND 
INSERT INTO students (id, programCode, programDescription, year) VALUES (100222222, 'a', 'b', 3)
```

This statement throws syntax error (`syntax error at or near "AND"`), and I don't understand why. I am connecting this SQL prepared statement through Java so my code is like this:

```java
String sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO users (id, password, firstName, lastName, emailAddress, enrollDate, lastAccess" + ", enabled, type) VALUES (100222222, 'password', 'Robert', 'McReady', 'bob.mcready@dcmail.ca', " + "'2016-03-07', '2015-09-03', 's', true)";
```

Is there a way so I can code this sqlInsert statement to insert into two different tables with different values in a single sql statement in Java?

Comment: This has to be two statements. In general, the way you make sure "both happen" is to put them into a transaction - this means that if anything fails, all the statements (both of them) are rolled back - so they fail or succeed together.

Comment: As the first comment said, the proper way to do that is to use a transaction. But, have you tried using `;` instead of `AND`?

Comment: I want to use this statement in Java so I have a string named sqlQuery that will store this prepared statement and I cannot place a semicolon on one.

Comment: I don't know anything about transaction!

Comment: MySQL is able to run multiple SQL statements at once (I think it's a bad idea), but not PostgreSQL. Just run one after the one and problem solved.

Comment: @TheImpaler: Postgres will happily run multiple statements in a single `execute()` call as long as they are properly terminated with `;`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I stand corrected. Just tested it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the goal is to avoid repeating the value for the ID column, this *could* be done using a data modifying CTE:

```
with data (id, password, firstname, lastname, emailaddress, enrolldate, lastaccess, enabled, type) as (
  VALUES (100222222, 'password', 'Robert', 'McReady', 'bob.mcready@dcmail.ca', '2016-03-07', '2015-09-03', true, 's') 
), new_user as (
  INSERT INTO users (id, password, firstname, lastname, emailaddress, enrolldate, lastaccess, enabled, type) 
  select id, password, firstname, lastname, emailaddress, enrolldate, lastaccess, enabled, type
  from data
)
INSERT INTO students (id, programcode, programdescription, year) 
select id, 'a', 'b', 3
from data;
```

Postgres also allows to run two statements with a single `Statement.executeUpdate()` call as long as they are delimited with a `;` (not with an "AND")

```java
String sqlInsert = "insert into users (...) values (...);" +
                   "insert into students (...) values (...);";
```

---

However the above is **not** the correct approach. You should **not** put the actual values directly into your SQL strings.

It's better (safer and more efficient) to use a `PreparedStatement`. As the ID will be stored in a Java variable, there is no need to repeat it.

This has the additional advantage that you can pass the values for the `DATE` columns as proper `LocalDate` instances rather than strings. If you insert both in a single transaction you make sure that either both rows or nothing is inserted.

Something like the following (without proper error handling and cleanup!)

```java
String usersInsert = "INSERT INTO users 
                    (id, password, firstname, lastname, emailaddress, enrolldate, lastaccess, enabled, type) 
                    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
String studentInsert = "INSERT INTO INSERT INTO students (id, programcode, programdescription, year)  values (?,?,?,?)"; 


// Start a transaction
connection.setAutocommit(false);

int id = 100222222;
PreparedStatement stmtUsers = connection.prepareStatement(usersInsert);
stmtUsers.setInt(1, id);
stmtUsers.setString(2, "password");
stmtUsers.setString(3, "Robert");
...
stmtUsers.setObject(6, LocalDate.of(2016,3,7), Types.DATE);
stmtUsers.setObject(7, LocalDate.of(2015,9,3), Types.DATE);
...
stmtUsers.executeUpdate();

PreparedStatement stmtStudent = connection.prepareStatement(studentInsert);
stmtStudent.setInt(1, id);
stmtStudent.setString(2, "a");
...

stmtStudent.executeUpdate();

// end the transaction
connection.commit();

stmtStudent.close();
stmtUsers.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to combine two insert statements with an AND. They need to be seperated.

In your code, depending on the language/framework, you can make one transaction for both statements, so they will be comitted at the same time to your DB.